# Fast way for solving symbolic system of equations in Matlab

Tags: matlab, equation

I have a system of equations with 100001 variables (x1 through x100000 and alpha) and exactly that many equations. Is there a computationally efficient way, in Matlab or otherwise, to solve this system of equations. I know of the solve() command, but I'm wondering if there is something that will run faster. The equations are of the form:

```
1.)      -x1 + alpha * (x4 + x872 + x9932) = 0
         .
         .
         .
100000.) -x100000 + alpha * (x38772 + x95) = 0
```

In other words, the i^th equation has variable xi with coefficient -1 added to alpha * (sum of some other variables) equals 0. The final equation is just that x1 + ... + x100000 = 1.

Comment: `alpha` is unknown also, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, I updated the question to reflect that.

Answer (score 3):

**The Math Part**

This system may be always brought to the eigen[value/vector] equation canonical form:

**A***x* = λ*x*

where **A** is your system's matrix, and *x* = [*x1*; *x2*; ...; *x100000*]. Taking the example from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16255827/solve-for-influence-of-nodes-in-graph-in-matlab), the system may be written down as:

```
/               \   /    \             /    \
| 0  1  0  0  0 |   | x1 |             | x1 |
| 0  0  1  0  1 |   | x2 |             | x2 |
| 1  0  0  0  0 | x | x3 | = (1/alpha) | x3 |
| 0  0  1  0  0 |   | x4 |             | x4 |
| 0  1  0  1  0 |   | x5 |             | x5 |
\               /   \    /             \    /
```

This means that your eigenvalues λ = 1/α. Of course, you should beware of complex eigenvalues (unless you really want to take them into account).

**The Matlab part**

Well this is much to your taste and skills. You can always find the eigenvalues of a matrix with `eig()`. Better to use sparse matrices (memory economy):

```
N = 100000;
A = sparse(N,N);
% Here's your code to set A's values
A_lambda = eig(A);

ieps= 0e-6;   % below this threshold imaginary part is considered null
alpha = real(1 ./ (A_lambda(arrayfun(@(x) imag(x)<ieps, A_lambda)))); % Chose Real. Choose Life. Choose a job. Choose a career. Choose a family. Choose a f****** big television, choose washing machines, cars, compact disc players and electrical tin openers. Choose good health, low cholesterol, and dental insurance. Choose fixed interest mortgage repayments. Choose a starter home. Choose your friends. Choose leisurewear and matching luggage. Choose a three-piece suit on hire purchase in a range of f****** fabrics. Choose DIY and wondering who the f*** you are on a Sunday morning. Choose sitting on that couch watching mind-numbing, spirit-crushing game shows, stuffing f****** junk food into your mouth. Choose rotting away at the end of it all, pissing your last in a miserable home, nothing more than an embarrassment to the selfish, f***** up brats you spawned to replace yourself. Chose life.

% Now do your stuff with alpha here
```

But, mind this: numerically solving large eigenvalue equations might give you complex values where real are expected. Tweak your `ieps` to sensible values, if you don't find anything in the beginning.

To find the eigenvectors, just take one out of the system and solve for the rest by means of Cramer's rule. The norm them to one if you wish so.